# How to fix react code which sometimes work fine sometimes not

Tags: reactjs

I wont to make an app which fetch some pics of NASA image of the day. I show the today's pic and some (4 for example) previous. I use datepicker to choose the image of the day of date by my choice. The problem is sometimes it work fine, sometimes shows only the today's photo, sometimes today's plus one or two previous. Can someone explain what's going on ?

I've reset the cookies, try it with Firefox and Chromium. I upload the code with DEMO_KEY but in my app use the key received after registration.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DateInput from "./components/DateInput.js";
import Photo from "./components/Photo.js";
import Axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
    currentPhoto: "",
    photos:[]
     };
   componentDidMount(){
    Axios
       .get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?&api_key=DEMO_KEY`)
       .then(response => this.setState({currentPhoto: response.data}));
    this.getImages(5);
     }
   getImages = n => {
    const daysBuffer = [];
 for(let i=1; i<n; i++){      
      let today = new Date();
      today.setDate(today.getDate()-i);
       daysBuffer.push(today);
    }
    const picBuffer = [];
    const datesBuffer = daysBuffer.map(day => this.getDate(day));
   datesBuffer.map(date => {
      Axios
       .get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date=${date}&api_key=DEMO_KEY`)
       .then(response => picBuffer.push(response.data));
    })
    this.setState({photos: picBuffer});
  }
  getDate = time => {
    let year = time.getFullYear();
    let month = time.getMonth();
    let day = time.getDate();
      return (
         `${year}-${month}-${day}`
        )
    };
   getPhoto = a => {
    let date = this.getDate(a);
    Axios
     .get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date=${date}&api_key=DEMO_KEY`)
     .then(response => this.setState({currentPhoto: response.data}))
  }
  changeDate = date => {
   this.setState({
    date
   });
   this.getPhoto(date);
  }
  render() {
      const imageGrid = this.state.photos.map(pic => {

               return (
                <ul>
                 <Photo photo = {pic} key={pic.date} />
                </ul>
                )
     })
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day</h1>
       <DateInput 
                 changeDate = {this.changeDate}
                 date = {this.state.date}
                 />
                 <Photo photo = {this.state.currentPhoto} />
                 {imageGrid}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

DateInput.js:

```
import React from "react";
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const DateInput = props => (
  <div>
   Select a Date: 
   <DatePicker

    selected = {props.date}
    onChange = {props.changeDate}
   />
  </div>
);

export default DateInput;

Photo.js

import React from 'react';

const Photo = props => (
      <div>
        <h3>{props.photo.title}</h3>
        <img src={props.photo.url} alt={props.photo.title} />
        <p>{props.photo.explanation}</p>

      </div>
    )

export default Photo;
```

Comment: your description is not clear.

Comment: Looks like you're missing some `async` and `await` keywords when resolving images.

Comment: NASA APIs have a rate limit. Maybe that's what is causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem in your code, is that you are taking synchronous action while you are retrieving images asynchronously.
The main problem lies in your **getImages** function

```
getImages = n => {
  const daysBuffer = [];
  for(let i=1; i<n; i++){      
    let today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate()-i);
    daysBuffer.push(today);
  }
  const picBuffer = [];
  const datesBuffer = daysBuffer.map(day => this.getDate(day));
  datesBuffer.map(date => {
    Axios
      .get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date=${date}&api_key=DEMO_KEY`)
      .then(response => picBuffer.push(response.data));
  })
  this.setState({photos: picBuffer}); //this line runs before Axios finishes
}
```

To fix this, without moving to async/await (which is better but requires restructuring), you would have to change the last few lines to this:

```
datesBuffer.map(date => {
  Axios
    .get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date=${date}&api_key=DEMO_KEY`)
    .then(response => {
      picBuffer.push(response.data);
      this.setState({photos: picBuffer});
    })
})
```

Notice that it is now setting the state many times, which is not ideal, but without knowing the capabalities of Axios regarding async/await this would be the most logical solution.

Comment: You are right,I fixed as you said and now everything works fine.Thank you :)